# Get Google analytics data using Oauth token?

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

Here I am using asp.net web to display Google analytic data. I am successfully able to get access token using oauth2.0. Using access token I am also get account information.

Here I want to get Google analytic data using access token. Please share link with me to get data using access token.

I have seen following code

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/Analytics_DataFeed_Sample/dataFeed.cs

But don't want to use it because here I have to pass user name and password:

```
 private const String CLIENT_USERNAME = "INSERT_LOGIN_EMAIL_HERE";
 private const String CLIENT_PASS = "INSERT_PASSWORD_HERE";
```

Let me know any way to get analytic data using access token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long work will get success.....

Here is Oauth playground made by Google developer from you can test your data

```
https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/
```

I just Oauth 2.0 for retrieve access token information after that I am using following URL for getting analytic information.

```
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed
```

you need to pass access token with your URL ie :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:12345&metrics=ga:visitors,ga:bounces&start-date=2012-07-01&end-date=2012-07-25&access_token=ya29.AHES6ZTzNR6n6FVcmY8uar6izjP9UGeHYNO5nUR7yU2bBqM
```

Best of luck Enjoy coding..

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code

```
string ClientId = "CLIENTID"
string ClientSecret = "CLIENTSECRET"
var Client = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, ClientId, ClientSecret);
var Auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(Client, Authenticate);

var Service = new AnalyticsService(Auth);

var Request = Service.Data.Ga.Get("profileID", StartDate, EndDate, "Matrix");
Request.MaxResults = 1000;
Request.Dimensions = "Dimensions";

var Result = Request.Fetch();
```